# Yitroh's Advise to Moses 4 - exaggeration?

Tags: parashas-yisro

When someone wants his advice to be heard and followed, he usually keeps the changes small, like if you want to advise your friend to change his $5000 car, you'd probably offer to buy a $10K or $20K but surely not $500K. Instead of offering to involve Aharon and his sons (5 men), or the Heads of the tribes (12 men) or the Elders (70 men), he offers to jump straight to a total of 78,000 judges.

Is this way of thinking reasonable?

Comment: 1. your numbers are wrong.  2. why not make a large change?  3. see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89010/16354 for why it is not such a major change

Answer (score 0):

According to Rashi ([18:18](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/18.18#e0n7) and [18:23](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/18.23#e0n7)), Aharon and the 70 Zekeinim (and others) were already helping Moshe with this.

See my comment above as well.

Comment: I'm not asking for some bread crumbs, here and there. I'm not a beginner and  I read Meforshim and their inconsistencies drive me mildly unstable. It is called "לדחות בקש". All of my questions seek for a true answer that's measured by consistency. If you don't have a consistent theory, I suggest you skip answering at all.

Comment: @AlBerko I provided a reason why Yisro did not suggest that a small number of others, such as the Zekeinim, because they were already involved in the process.  The Rishonim(and the Acharonim) by and large have consistent theories for these stories, if you want I can post one in its entirely when I have a bit of spare time later.  Which one of your questions would yo like me to post it to?

Comment: What do you mean by _"were already involved in the process."_

Comment: @alberko they were already judges.

Comment: Who says that and to what degree of confidence and so what's לבדך?

Comment: @AlBerko As I pointed out, Rashi says it. Twice.  Levadecha could just be that the whole group was counted as an individual.

Answer (score -1):

your PR rules are true for us small people. Moshe Rabbeinu had his way of running klal yisroel, and Yisro had another idea. Yisro gave his full plan, there was no need for negotiation. We are dealing with great people who are all seeking only the truth.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.